# Add jquery as a separate file in head via webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack

Is there a way to add script (eg. jquery) from node_modules as a separate file to the < head > tag with webpack? This is the part where I generate templates with HtmlWebpackPlugin so I wiould like to inject the script to all

```
    let templates = fs.readdirSync('src/templates').filter(file => (path.extname(file) === '.html'))
    templates.map(page => {
        webpackConfiguration.plugins.push(new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
          template: 'src/templates/' + page,
          filename: page,
          hash: true
        }))
    })
```

I know there was option called headerScripts in webpack config while ago but this seems not to be working.

Comment: How does your entry section look like?

Comment: @Legends: 
entry: {
   main: ['@babel/polyfill', './src/js/scripts.js']
}

Comment: This `main` entry should be used by all templates?
Don't understand what you are trying to achieve, besides your mentioned problem.

Comment: yes, all templates should use main

Comment: And you do't want to use a cdn version of `jquery`? 
You want `jquery` not to be bundled but referenced from `node_modules`?
I am confused...